# Creating Kotlin classes in Android Studio using intention actions

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When using Java on Android Studio I must often don't have to create files, I just type the name of the class I want to use and use "Intent Actions" to solve the problem and create the necessary file. The problem is, when using Kotlin, if I need, lets say an Interface, when I hit the Intent Action, Android Studio creates that Interface in the same file I'm working on, instead of providing a dialog for package selection as it does for Java. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This just happens to be the default behaviour in Kotlin because the restrictions on what you can put in a file are weaker.

One fairly quick and painless solution to this is to immediately invoke intention actions on the newly created interface, and choose `Move 'MyInterface' to a separate file`. This moves it into a separate file within the same package/folder.

If you want to move it to a different package, <kbd>F6</kbd> is the default shortcut for moving a class or interface to somewhere else, which you can also invoke when the cursor is on the new interface.

Comment: seriously? 2018 and this is still not patched :(